# Handling calendar based data with REST

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data, django-rest-framework, restful-architecture

I have the following Data model -

```
"Room":
   "id": 1
   "name": "Deluxe"
   "description": "A big room"
    ...


"Inventory":
     "room_id" : 1
     "date"  :  "27/04/2015"
     "availability" : 10 //Given a date the number of rooms available
```

The use cases for UI would be (Mock below) - 
For a Room -

1. set availability for a single day
2. set availability for multiple days at once

-- by selecting the date(s) from calendar in one go.

[image]

Going the Primary/Unique keys I can consider Inventory for a day as Resource and issue multiple post/put calls for each day. But it might be overkill to issue multiple requests.

We are using Ember Data REST Adapter on the client side/Django Rest framework on the server side.

Are there any suggested REST patterns to deal with this kind time/day based data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The notion of `Inventory` as an editable resource seems like a bit of an anti-pattern here.  I would think that the `Inventory` is most logically determined by the existence of one or more `Reservation` resources, which would mean that `Inventory` is immutable (as it logically should be) and only exists so you don't have to pull all the reservations client-side (which shouldn't be allowed anyway) and determine availability from there.

So my suggestion is to create a `Reservation` model that has `room_id`, `start_date` and `end_date`, and any GET requests to inventory simply returns the availability for the requested date range.  This eliminates the need for multiple updates entirely.

Comment: Unfortunately we can not derive availability from number of Reservations - the user has freedom to set availability to any number. I added a mock to explain the use case better.

Comment: In that case, the only convention I can suggest is JSON-patch (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902) or creating a custom batch endpoint that can efficiently handle your use case.  Some people shy away from the JSON-patch RFC because they think it's unweildy and the additional complexity doesn't warrant its use versus just making multiple requests.... but I trust you can form your own opinion about that.